# MongoDB Stitch Customize New User Email Confirmations

Tags: mongodb-stitch

I am using MongoDB Stitch Email/Password provider. When a new user registers, is there a way to customize the emails sent for confirmation?

If not, is it possible to preempt these emails from being sent and just build the functionality myself. In other words, Stitch would still maintain the user/password authentication, and I would just program the mail confirmation process.

I know with Firebase they limit the editing of these emails because it can be used for spam, so the only option is to write it yourself. I prefer to do this rather than use the Stitch 'Custom Authentication' provider because I would then have to create the entire user management process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is only a single method for confirming Email/Password users. There is no way to customise or skipping the confirmation. However, this is on the roadmap and hopefully will be supported soon.

Comment: Is there any update on this? A hesitation I have for using Stitch is the lack of control for aspects of my app, such as this

Comment: @MikeBird please follow this canny ticket https://mongodb.canny.io/stitch-internal/p/allow-users-to-specify-a-function-for-user-confirmation .It is currently in progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Cognito as the [custom authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authenticati%E2%80%A6). With AWS Cognito you can customize the email/sms.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/authentication/userpass/#configuration

Users may choose one of three ways to handle user confirmation:

1. Send a Confirmation Email
2. Run a Confirmation Function
3. Automatically Confirm Users

Users can choose one of two ways to handle password resets:

1. Send a Password Reset Email
2. Run a Password Reset Function